# Angularjs 2 nested interface

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ngmodel

Am new to angularjs. please look at the code i cant even know how to explain this one

**interface**

```
export interface ScanuploadInterface {
   docVia string;customFields:Array<any>;
   associateDocs :Array<any>;
}
```

**model** :

```
import {ScanuploadInterface} from '../../interfaces/scanupload.interface'; 
holeDocument = <ScanuploadInterface>{};
```

**html :** doing ***ngFor** for dynamic input fields

```
<input id="{{list.fieldName}}" name="{{list.fieldName}}" type="{{list.fieldType}}" class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="holeDocument.customFields[list.fieldName]" >
```

but this one throws a error as

> **Cannot read property 'field12' of undefined**

field12 is a dynamic value comes from list.fieldName.
I don't know how to solve this one. Any kind of solution is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you initializing your customFields? It says holeDocument.customFields is undefined

Comment: at my interface, see 2nd line in my interface header and imported at model see 1st line.@AliBaig

Comment: That's just the declaration, not the initialization. As far as I can see you haven't assigned anything to customFields using = operator.

Comment: oh..umm..but the property 'field12' is comes dynamically(fecthing from DB), in this case how can we initialise it ?

Comment: Can you post its value if its coming from db? Just use console.log and post it here

Answer (score 0):

yes,i fixed by initialising the object in **ngOnInit**, it work's.
**code :**
  **interface :**

```
export interface ScanuploadInterface {
   docVia string;customFields:any;
   associateDocs :any;
}
```

**model :**

```
import {ScanuploadInterface} from '../../interfaces/scanupload.interface'; 
holeDocument = <ScanuploadInterface>{}; ngOnInit(){this.holeDocument.customFields = {};
        this.holeDocument.associateDocs = {};}
```

**html :** doing ***ngFor** for dynamic input fields

```
<input id="{{list.fieldName}}" name="{{list.fieldName}}" type="{{list.fieldType}}" class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="holeDocument.customFields[list.fieldName]" >
```

Thanks for your response guys.